# Select all rows in quasar table programatically

Tags: quasar-framework

I need to select all rows in a quasar 1.22  table and not only visible rows.

I have tried the method 'selectAllRows' below. But the selection checkbox stays unchecked.

```
<q-table
                ref="tablePartic"
                :key="tkey"
                flat
                dense
                bordered
                square
                class="q-mt-xs"
                title="Participantes"
                :data="participantes"
                :columns="columns"
                :loading="loading"
                row-key="number"
                :selected-rows-label="getSelectedString"
                selection="multiple"
                :filter="filter"
                :selected.sync="selected"
                :pagination="pagination"
              />
methods: {
    selectAllRows() {
      this.selected = []
      this.selected = [...this.participantes.map((o) => o.number)]
    },
```

Comment: it should be only       this.selected = this.participantes

Answer (score 0):

If you observe your selected variable, you will see that it contains the entire object, not just your row key, so the comment of @Pratick Patel is the correct way

```
this.selected = [... **your data array object]
```

PS: with this, you can also filter the select all behavior in the slot of `v-slot:header-selection`

```
    const selectAllOnlineStatus = (): void => {
        selected.value = [...entities.filter((entity) => entity.status === Status.Online)];
    };
    
<template v-slot:header-selection="props">
    <q-checkbox v-model="props.selected" @click="selectAllOnlineStatus" />
</template>
```